# How do I get the current filename of a Word document, without the extension or full path, using a macro?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have code that extracts the full path of a file, minus the extension, and I'm trying to modify it to only store the name of the file, once again without the extension.

```
Sub ShowFilename()

Dim pathName As String
With ActiveDocument
If Len(.Path) = 0 Then
.Save
End If
If Right(.Name, 1) = "x" Then
pathName = Left$(.FullName, (Len(.FullName) - 5))
Else
pathName = Left$(.FullName, (Len(.FullName) - 4))
End If
End With
MsgBox pathName

End Sub
```

This displays `C:\Users\test`, and the document's name is `test.docm`. How can I modify this to only display the filename? Do I need to split the string along `\` and extract the last part?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

FSO has a set of methods for this type of thing, one of which is "getBaseName"

```
Msgbox CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject").getbasename(o.Name)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhxzwwe1(v=vs.84).aspx

Comment: Nice and short. I quite like this.

Answer (score 7):

```
Sub ShowFilename()
Dim pathName As String
Dim o As Document
Set o = ActiveDocument
If InStrRev(o.Name, ".") <> 0 Then
    MsgBox Left(o.Name, InStrRev(o.Name, ".") - 1)
Else
    MsgBox o.Name
End If
End Sub
```

I initially posted this without the if, which would error if the file had never been saved, or had no extension.

Answer (score 3):

As I was not able write code using FSO (isn't it only for VB, is it?), I wrote this one, quite self explanatory :)

```
Dim oldFilename As String

oldFilename = ActiveDocument.Name
If Right(oldFilename, 5) = ".docx" Then
    MsgBox ("subtract .docx")
    oldFilename = Left(oldFilename, Len(oldFilename) - 5)
ElseIf Right(oldFilename, 4) = ".doc" Then
    MsgBox ("subtract .doc")
    oldFilename = Left(oldFilename, Len(oldFilename) - 4)
Else
    MsgBox ("no extension yet")
End If
```

Comment: You can use FSO with VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Yeish, I wouldn't do it like that!

Hypothetically, you have a whole folders worth of word and you don't need the extensions, you just want the names. What you would do is go through the word docs and parse them through this function with the type of extension you want removed from the file name

```
Function removeExtension(myDoc as Document, extension as String)
Dim documentWithoutExtension as String

documentWithoutExtension = replace(myDoc.Name, extension, "")

removeExtension = documentWithoutExtension

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me.

```
Sub ShowFilename()
MsgBox ActiveWindow.Parent
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way would be:

```
Sub Test1()
Dim DocName As Document
Set DocName = ActiveDocument
end sub
```