# Vba insert file name in footer of word doc

Tags: vba, ms-word

This is the code I have for the footer, but I need to insert a field for the file name. Any help would be great!

```
With wdapp.ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Footers(1).range.Paragraphs(1)
    .range.Text = "AA SERVICE COMPANY - Heating & Cooling" & vbCr & "550 ANTHONY TRAIL; NORTHBROOK, IL 60062" & vbCr & "Phone:"
    .range.InsertAfter vbCr & "Page "
    Set r = .range
    E = .range.End
    r.Start = E
    .range.Fields.Add r, wdFieldPage
    .range.InsertAfter " of "
    E = .range.End
    r.Start = E
    .range.Fields.Add r, wdFieldNumPages
    .Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight
    End With
```

Comment: Have you tried record macro to add the Filename *Field*? Something like `Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="FILENAME  \p ", PreserveFormatting:=True`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the current filename of a Word document, without the extension or full path, using a macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564857/how-do-i-get-the-current-filename-of-a-word-document-without-the-extension-or-f)

Comment: How would I attach this to 'With wdapp.ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Footers(1).range.Paragraphs‌​(1)